# I need to know how can i find my post id in telegram?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I would like to know how can i get the post id like this example from telegram official site (e.g., t.me/durov/43) when i am posting some news in my channel i want to get the post-id and call that post from my another group with url link.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the post link with some Telegram apps like Telegram X (Android), Telegram Desktop. Explore your channel and touch (on mobile) or right click (on desktop) to the message, then select the "Copy Post Link". It'll copy the url of the post.

After that, you can share this with your group. Also, it contains the id of the post.